# how to upload files via FileZilla google compute engine

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine

I am new to Google Compute Engine. I already installed Apache and MySQL, but I have been unable to to find a way to connect to the server in FileZilla. How do I do that? Also, how can I get access to phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

With FileZilla, you should use sftp as described on the [FileZilla wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto). See also a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162854/sftp-into-google-compute-engine) on alternative methods for uploading files to your instance and make sure that port 22 is open in your firewall as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22283980/3618671).

For phpMyAdmin, consider using an [ssh tunnel](http://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/ssh-tunnelling-explained/). To create a tunnel, you just need to pass the right args to `ssh` via `gcutil`, where `$A` is the local port (must be unused on your local machine) and `$B` is the remote port (i.e., the port phpMyAdmin is listening to on the remote host):

```
gcutil --project=[...] ssh --ssh_arg -L$A:localhost:$B <instance-name>
```

Then, you can connect to `localhost:$A` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already have a Private key(.ppk) for connecting SSH.
For connect to Filezilla you have to change Private key to Public key.
1. launch Filezilla and select Edit->Settings->SFTP
2. Select Add key file.
3. Select your Private Key and Filezilla will make new public key by using your private key.
4. Now You can connect your server by SFTP in Filezilla