# SFTP into Google Compute Engine from windows 7 Client

Tags: cygwin, sftp, ssh-keys, google-compute-engine, windows-client

I am trying to `SFTP` a `Debian-7-Wheezy-V20140807` Instance on Google Compute Engine from Windows 7, 64 Bit Client.

[**Finally my problem got solved using this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958085/accessing-ftp-on-google-compute-engine)

Also in Windows I first installed Cygwin and then used set the Environment Variable `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` to python instead of `C:\python27\python.exe`

and finally from `cygwin` ran this

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

All the instructions below are symptoms. First i tried Filezilla, which errors out with message

> ```
> Status:   Waiting to retry...
> Status:   Connecting to 23.xx.xx.xx..
> Response: fzSftp started
> Command:  open "Abdul@23.236.51.19" 22
> Error:    Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
> Error:    Could not connect to server
>
> User     :root
>
> password : 
> <same as passphrase set up on running SSH key>
> ```

I have also tried `gcloud compute copy-files`

```
gcloud compute copy-files deccan4-clone:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key.pub --zone=us-central1-b
```

> ```
> ssh_host_rsa_key.pub: **Permission denied
> ERROR**: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) exit code 1: /usr/bin/scp -i /home/Abdul/.ssh/google_compute_engine
> ```

```
sudo gcloud compute copy-files deccan4-clone:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key.pub --zone=us-central1-b
```

> ```
> WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for Google Compute Engine.
> WARNING: ssh-keygen will be executed to generate a key.
> This tool needs to create the directory /root/.ssh before being able
> to generate SSH keys.
>
> Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
>
> Generating public/private rsa key pair.
> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
> Enter same passphrase again:
> Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/google_compute_engine.
> Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub.
> The key fingerprint is:
>  root@deccan4-clone
>
> **ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) some requests did not succeed:
>  - Insufficient Permission**
> ```

I have also tried

```
Abdul@deccan4-clone:/home/a_rahman_synergywell_com$ gcloud compute copy-files de                                                                                                            ccan4-clone:test.txt  test.txt --zone=us-central1-b
```

> ```
> scp: test.txt: No such file or directory
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) exit code 1: /usr/bin/scp -i /home/Abdul/.ssh                                                      
> /google_compute_engine -r Abdul@23.236.51.19:test.txt test.txt
> ```

Please let me know if I am missing some key setup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958085/accessing-ftp-on-google-compute-engine