# Can I use an FTP access to my files on my VM?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created folders through the online SSH command-line of my instance. Can I see and edit my folders and files with an FTP access, or I have to use only the online command-line ?

Thanks !

Comment: That would open a security threat to your machine. Why don't you use Google Cloud Storage as a place to put the files you'd like to get from the server?

Comment: As @KaiWen said, you should use SFTP rather than FTP as it's more secure. See also responses to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22162854/3618671). Do you have a preferred SFTP client in mind? If it supports SSH keys, you should be able to configure to use it.

Comment: I don't use GCS because i want to manipulate my NodeJS and MongoDB files that i installed with the command-line.
Yes it's a mistake, i wanted to say 'SFTP'. But i saw others responses and i tried to configure a SFTP directly on my Debian instance, however it doesn't work...

Comment: @AlexandreLorret please be specific about what doesn't work: what have you tried, what exact messages/errors are you getting, etc. Please revise your question with this information.

Comment: Sorry, i thought that was not important because i tried to install the 'openssh_server' package, i thought it existed an official technique to access on the server via SFTP.
So i installed 'apt-get install ssh openssh-server'. But i can't use 'addgroup sftp_chroot' to create a group of users who can access on the SFTP (the command addgroup doesn't exist). I also tried to change the port 22 but i can't edit the file '/etc/ssh/sshd_config' (i use the 'vi' command but the file is readonly).
It seems i'ts impossible to edit the files system...

Answer (score 1):

How about sftp? It's almost boarded with the linux distribution. There are many gui front end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely do that. You will need to setup an FTP server (e.g. VSFTPD).

Comment: Thanks but how do i can find my login and my password ? I think my IP adress is the IP of my instance.