# Google Cloud FTP and SSH Access

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I just started using the free trial of google cloud. How can I access my VM using ssh and ftp/sftp? I googled a bit, but couldnt find much

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22203728/3618671) for `sftp`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27536795/3618671) for using plain `ssh` with public/private key authentication, instead of passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it, you have to /etc/ssh/sshd_config
And change 
PasswordAuthentication no to yes. 
Then you use sudo service ssh restart
To restart the ssh daemon. Then use sudo passwd to change the root password. Now you can ssh/sftp using username root and password what you just set

Comment: I know this is a bad answer, I will change it when I have more time

Answer (score 0):

Use the new tool [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) for ssh'ing and other operations on your VM instances: `gcloud compute ssh example-instance`

Comment: Is there no way to use the normal ssh/ftp protovol?

Comment: You can use ssh client like putty to ssh into the instance. You can follow the steps on this link[1] to setup your ssh keys.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console#sshkeys

Comment: Note that `gcloud compute ssh` will call `ssh` under the covers; you can replicate what it does as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27536795/3618671).