# How to access SSH keys for a Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine VM instance?

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys, gcloud-compute

I created a new instance via the Google Cloud web console from a CentOS 6.x image. I saw a blank on the creation form where I could paste in an existing SSH key; since this was my first instance, I didn't have one yet. I assumed it would take me through the key creation process like Amazon EC2 does. It didn't.

The instance appears to be created, but I can't figure out how to get the SSH key for it. The instance web page has a button that says "SSH" and it let me log in briefly via a pop-up web browser window that simulates an SSH session. However, it only let me into a user-level account, not `root`. The pop-up had a menu item to change the user and changing it to `root` does nothing but generate connection errors.  Now I can't log into my instance at all!

I've searched but can't find any straight-forward documentation that explains this aspect of Google Compute instances.

Do I have to create my own SSH keys manually and paste them into the form during instance creation?  Is there an obvious step I'm missing?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

By default, a new Google Compute Engine (GCE) VM instance does not have SSH keys pre-assigned to it, so you cannot "retrieve" them as they don't exist—it's up to you to create them, or use a tool like `gcloud` (see below) which will prompt you to create them if you don't have SSH keys yet.

You have several options for connecting to your newly-created GCE VM.

One option is to connect using the "SSH" button in the Developer Console GUI next to the instance in the list of instances, which will open a browser window and a terminal session to the instance.

If you would like to connect via SSH client on the command-line, you can use [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) tool (part of the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)):

```
gcloud compute ssh example-instance
```

You can see the full set of flags and options on the [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) help page, along with several examples.

If you don't already have SSH keys, it will prompt you to create them and then connect to the instance. If you already have keys, you can use existing SSH keys, which it will transfer to the instance.

By default, `gcloud` expects keys to be located at the following paths:

- `$HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine` – private key
- `$HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub` – public key

If you want to reuse keys from a different location with `gcloud`, consider either making symlinks or pointing `gcloud` there using the [`--ssh-key-file`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) flag.

**Note:** if you don't use `gcloud` at all, you have to manually add the SSH keys to the instance's metadata as described in [Setting up ssh keys at the instance level](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) which you can do via `gcloud` or manually via [Google Cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/console).

You can also create your own keys using `ssh-keygen` which is what `gcloud` will also use under the covers. You can connect to the instance [using `ssh` directly](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#standardssh) instead of `gcloud` but you will need to specify extra parameters to do so:

```
ssh -i KEY_FILE -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
    -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    USER@IP_ADDRESS
```

which will require the following parameters:

- `KEY_FILE` – [Required] The file where the keys are stored on the computer, e.g., `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`.
- `USER` – [Required] The username to log in that instance. Typically, this is the username of the local user running `gcloud compute`.
- `IP_ADDRESS` – [Required] The external IP address of the instance.

For more details, see the [SSH docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#sshing).

Comment: I think you're saying that when a new instance is created there are no ssh keys? And I can't create ssh keys in the conventional manner that I would for a CentOS server. Instead I have to create the ssh keys using the Google tool glcoud. But once created, I can ssh to the instance normally (i.e. without gcloud or the the web-based ssh). I'll give it a try. Only remaining question is whether that will get me root access. On EC2 you set the root ssh keys during instance creation and then create user-level ssh keys later. Is the ssh key generated by gcloud the root key?

Comment: There are no SSH keys added to the instance by default. I've updated the answer for info on using `sshk-keygen` and `ssh` directly. Your login will be same as your local username but it will have passwordless `sudo` access so you won't login as `root` directly but `sudo` will give you `root` access privileges.

Comment: @MishaBrukman it's asking for the passphrase of $HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine . What will be it? I did not create any passphrase for this.

Comment: @MishaBrukman it's asking for the passphrase of $HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine . What will be it? I did not create any passphrase for this.

Comment: @AnuranBarman — if you created the key `$HOME/.ssh/google_compute_engine` without providing a password, then you can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when it asks for the password. You can also run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` and if you can add it successfully without providing a password, that should work with `gcloud` as well. If that doesn't work, you can just remove that key and create one manually with `ssh-keygen` and then you'll know the password for it as you'll have to specify it to create the key.

Comment: I specifically use AWS over GCP for this particular reason.

Answer (score 43):

To login to instance using ssh- [All steps performed on Linux Ubuntu 16.04]

1. Create a SSH Key `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/gcloud_instance1 -C varunon9` here 
   `gcloud_instance1` is name of key file and `varunon9` is username
2. Print the content of public key file `cd ~/.ssh && cat gcloud_instance1.pub`
3. Click on Edit VM instance details icon [image]
4. Paste the content of public key file (output of `cd ~/.ssh && cat gcloud_instance1.pub`) in ssh-keys text-area

   [image]  [image]
5. Click on Save
6. From terminal now you can login to your instance via ssh `ssh -i gcloud_instance1 varunon9@35.200.201.56` where `gcloud_instance1` is private key file (in .ssh directory) and `varunon9` is username and `35.200.201.56` is external IP of your instance.

Comment: What is the UserName in this context? ex. in the VM terminal someName@instanceName:~$

Comment: @Billy - in Google Cloud Platform the username is the key comment (`varunon9` in answer example) and it must match the username you are trying to login with. [see this](https://superuser.com/q/516912/297406)

Answer (score 9):

**Easiest way for creating and using one pair of ssh keys for multiple instances:**

**Step 1:** Install putty and puttyGen from https://putty.org/

**Step 2:** Open a terminal in your local desktop / laptop (in Windows 10 and later you use Windows Linux Subsystem)

Type: ssh-keygen

Enter a name for the filename at the prompt: e.g. google_key

2 files will be created google_key and google_key.pub

**Step 3:** Copy the entire contents of the google_key.pub

Note there is no new line character. It should all be in one line.

**Step 4:** Before creating any VM instance, go to [Compute Engine -> Metadata](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata)

Select "SSH keys" tab and click "Add SSH" keys

Paste the contents of the google_key.pub. If you pasted the contents properly, you should see the ***username*** appear on the left label. Then hit save.

**Step 5:** Now create your favorite VM instance under google compute.

Copy the External IP ***vm_instance_external_ip***

Go back to your linux terminal and type

ssh -i google_key.pub ***username***@***vm_instance_external_ip***

Type "yes"

And now you should be good to go.

If you need video instructions, [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzKH-FL1xxU)

Comment: Omg, got it fixed after two days. Thank-you man. The video link at the end was the most helpful part in my case. I guess the error was that I had repeatedly been creating the VM instance first, and then assigning the sshkey in the Metadata section. I still don't know.

Comment: when I click on save, it says Invalid key. Required format: <protocol> <key-blob> <username@example.com> or <protocol> <key-blob> google-ssh {"userName":"<username@example.com>","expireOn":"<date>"} - could you paste how the content of google_key.pub looks at you?

Answer (score 4):

To populate SSH config files in your machine use:

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that wants to add project-wide SSH keys to their Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project, `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`:

1. Generate an Ed25519-based SSH key:

   ```sh
   ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "$(whoami)@$(hostname)"

   #=>

   Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (/. . ./.ssh/id_ed25519):
   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
   Enter same passphrase again:
   Your identification has been saved in id_ed25519.
   Your public key has been saved in id_ed25519.pub.
   The key fingerprint is:
   SHA256:. . . "$(whoami)@$(hostname)"
   The key's randomart image is:
   +--[ED25519 256]--+
   |      . . .      |
   +----[SHA256]-----+
   ```
2. Install the Google Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install)
3. Make sure you're logged-in as the correct user:

   ```sh
   gcloud config list --format="value(core.account)"
   ```

   if not, log-in using:

   ```sh
   gcloud auth login
   ```
4. Make sure you're connected to `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME` with:

   ```sh
   gcloud config list --format="value(core.project)"
   ```

   if not, switch to `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME` with:

   ```sh
   gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_NAME
   ```
5. Making use of the `filter()` and `firstof()` [transforms](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#Transforms) available for `gcloud` allows your to avoid generating a temporary file and only use a **single** command to add that SSH key to `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`:

   ```sh
   gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
   --metadata ssh-keys="$(gcloud compute project-info describe \
   --format="value(commonInstanceMetadata.items.filter(key:ssh-keys).firstof(value))")
   $(whoami):$(cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub)"

   #=>

   Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME].
   ```
6. You *should* now see that Ed25519-based SSH key now in `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`; check with:

   ```sh
   gcloud compute project-info describe \
   --format="value(commonInstanceMetadata.items.filter(key:ssh-keys).firstof(value))"
   ```

Using [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) to just secure shell into a Compute virtual machine (VM) is as easy as:

1. Find the external IP (`$GCP_VM_ADDRESS`) for the VM you wish to secure shell into with:

   ```sh
   gcloud compute instances list \
   --format=table"[box=true](name:label=NAME, networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[].natIP.flatten():label=EXTERNAL_IP)"

   #=>

   ┌──────────────┬─────────────────┐
   │     NAME     │  EXTERNAL_IP    │
   ├──────────────┼─────────────────┤
   │     . . .    │      . . .      │
   │ $GCP_VM_NAME │ $GCP_VM_ADDRESS │
   │     . . .    │      . . .      │
   └──────────────┴─────────────────┘
   ```

   **Note**: if you haven't created a VM yet, be sure to follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage).
2. You *should* now be able to just:

   ```sh
   ssh $(whoami)@$GCP_VM_ADDRESS
   ```

Comment: This looks excellent, but I still get permission denied when I try it. I read somewhere that Google VMs don't like trying to login with root, but it doesn't seem to work for other users either.

Answer (score 2):

I found a useful button that helps avoiding the guessing game for the different gcloud parameters, such as versionId, serviceId, etc.

*View gcloud command* --> 
[image: ssh screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going crazy trying this

Answer (score 1):

Once you open the console, try to view gcloud command in the ssh tab. The gcloud client will open with the following command.

gcloud compute --project  ssh --zone

And if its first time, it will create ssh key for you. You just need to download the file at this location *~/.ssh/google_compute_engine* using the gcloud client download file option on top right. Once you have the key file, just issue

ssh -i  username@external_IP

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue where I create a ssh key on one google compute and copy the publid key over to another google compute and then try to ssh from one node to another. However, I get as permission error. To fix this will I have to follow similar steps as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Concept is simple,
if you have SSH private key you can connect to Server answer given by above is @isma is easy one

so

- create SSH keys: ssh-keygen in desktop-shell/GCP-sdk which generates  Public/Private key
- put Public keys in Gcloud Compute- SSH
- now connect from desktop-shell/GCP-sdk using
  ssh -i google_key username@vm_instance_external_ip

OR

Use putty download Private key mentioned by @Abubacker
and open  Putty

- give Ip address
- open Private key in SSH-Auth