# Debian wheezy Linux guest environment not available

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Since yesterday I can't connect through `ssh` to all of my Debian wheezy instances on my google cloud. I can connect only through the web console. When the web console tries to negotiate the session, there's a message telling me to update the Linux guest environment. But for wheezy, there is no Linux guest environment package.

Do you have any idea to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian 7 images were [deprecated a while a go](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/eMYFdtVvWK0/discussion) and as there are no update packages for the [Guest Environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment), the best approach would be to migrate to [Debian 8 or 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html).

To access your VMs you might try one of the following options:

1) According to this  [public issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/67997017#comment4) the old guest environment still work with deprecated keys. If you have an [SSH client configured with an old private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535945/how-to-get-the-ssh-keys-for-a-new-google-compute-engine-instance/27536795#27536795), you might still have access to your VMs through it.

2) Accessing the VM via the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)

3) Mounting, as secondary, the original disk or a copy of it in a VM you do have access to. The steps are very similar to the section [“Inspect an instance without shutting it down” on this document"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting). That would allow you to recover your data.