# Jenkins deployment on GCP VM via shell script

Tags: jenkins, deployment, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform and want to build a deployment pipeline via Jenkins. I have a virtual machine up and running that I connect via SSH button given on the dashboard and do deployments.

Unlike AWS where I get **pem** file to connect... I don't have a file to connect here. Now, in Jenkins when **I want to connect via shell script** and deploy latest code on VM - I don't know how to do it.

something like

> ssh -i @some-file name:ip

Kindly help as to how can I connect/ssh gcp vm via shell in Jenkins and make deployments. Step by step answer needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are still PEM files stored in the VM instance, you can locate them in $HOME/.ssh.
See this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535945/how-to-get-the-ssh-keys-for-a-new-google-compute-engine-instance) about how to retrieve SSH keys on GCE

Comment: yes, Google offers fully managed SSH keys if you want, otherwise, the SSH protocol is pretty standard for Linux regardless of the Cloud provider