# Bitbucket pipeline ssh to compute engine instance with gcloud

Tags: bitbucket, google-compute-engine, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using Bitbucket pipelines to run deploy script on preemptable machines on compute engine. I use google sdk and service account with Owner role, but still can't ssh to the machine.
that is how my bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks like:

```
- echo $GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./gcloud-api-key.json
- gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-api-key.json
- gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT
- gcloud compute --project $GCLOUD_PROJECT ssh --zone "us-east1-c" $INSTANCE_NAME --command "./deploy"
```

I can see that I am able to successfully authenticate:

```
Activated service account credentials for: [...]
```

but I am still failing on ssh to instance

```
    gcloud compute --project "..." ssh --zone "us-east1-c" "..." --command "..."
WARNING: The public SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: The private SSH key file for gcloud does not exist.
WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/google_compute_engine.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub.
The key fingerprint is: ...
...
Updating project ssh metadata...
................Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/...].
done.
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
Warning: Permanently added '...' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Am I missing something? My understanding was once I authenticate as service account with permissions perform ssh, gcloud ssh command suppose to work

Comment: This is a basic SSH issue, similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535945/how-to-get-the-ssh-keys-for-a-new-google-compute-engine-instance?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: I think I did, but I don't remember how.  I'll update the answer if I recall the details

Comment: My initial issue was that the service account needs roles/compute.osLogin as well as roles/iam.serviceAccountUser on the VM service account. I think I'm stuck granting permission for a bitbucket deployer service account to act as the VM service account.

Answer (score 0):

- This is a basic SSH issue,
- Please check this thread [1].

[1] [How to get the ssh keys for a new Google Compute Engine instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535945/how-to-get-the-ssh-keys-for-a-new-google-compute-engine-instance?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I read the thread but could not understand what am i doing wrong. As you stated in the thread: "If you don't already have SSH keys, it will prompt you to create them and then connect to the instance."
 AFAIU that is what happening when  i see those log lines

WARNING: You do not have an SSH key for gcloud.
WARNING: SSH keygen will be executed to generate a key.
Waiting for SSH key to propagate

I still can't connect afterwards