# FTP on lampstack - Google cloud platform

Tags: ftp, google-cloud-platform

So I installed a LAMP on a Google Cloud instance with debain wheezy7. Everything is working fine but I am not able to work the ftp. I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04) tutorial by digital ocean

I am stuck at this last step where I need to make vsftpd allow the user to write outside the chroot file.

The error is get is

`hetunandu_gmail_com@lamp:~$ mkdir /root/hetunandu/files
mkdir: cannot create directory /root/hetunandu/files': Permission denied`

Then when i use sudo with it i get this error

`hetunandu_gmail_com@lamp:~$ sudo mkdir /root/hetunandu/files
mkdir: cannot create directory /root/hetunandu/files': No such file or directory`

Where do I go from here?

Also I dont know how to get my username and password setup for FTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the tutorial and could not replicate your issue. I initially got "Permission denied" but you can circumvent this by running:

```
$ sudo su
```

and then

```
$ mkdir -p /root/$USER/files
```

Why not use /home/$USER ? not sure why you want to create the folders under /root.

As for your second question, regarding the username and password, I am not sure I understand. From the Developers Console > Compute Engine > VM Instances > click SSH and that should log you in with root privileges. then you can create all the users you want:

```
$ sudo adduser test_user
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use FTP as it's an *insecure clear-text protocol* which will let others see your password and easily get access your instance, read/modify/delete your files, etc.

Instead, you should use *secure protocols* such as SCP or SFTP with public key authentication.

Here are some options to transfer files to/from your GCE VM instance:

- `sftp` CLI tool, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22203728/3618671)
- `gcloud compute copy-files`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23699894/3618671)
- [WinSCP with SFTP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_google_compute_engine)